# Does OCaml garbage collect intermediate results?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

suppose I have a function

```
let rec f x = 
    let a = (* build a huge list, possibly used f on smaller input again here *) in 
    let b = (* build a huge list, possibly used f on smaller input again too *) in
    List.append a b
```

My question is that after calling `f` is `a` and `b` freed? My program is eating up my memory and I am suspecting whether this is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it will be freed. OCaml garbage collection usually doesn't leak, and if value is not reachable it will be collected. If it is possible to reuse memory it will be reused.

Note, if you're using really big data structures, then maybe list is not a good choice, especially concatenating lists with `concat` is very inefficient.

Comment: "then maybe maps is not a good choice", I suspect you mean that lists are not very good choice?

Comment: haha, yep, lists are bad choice. And yes, `set` or `map` may suite better.

Answer (score 2):

After `f` returns its value, the variables `a` and `b` can't be accessed. So the value of `a` will be garbage collected eventually. For the most obvious implementation of `List.append`, the value of `b` forms part of the result of the function. So it won't be garbage collected until this result is no longer accessible.

If you have a memory leak you need to look in places that are accessible for the whole computation. One example would be a large global table.

Comment: Appending lists in a call-by-value language is generally not great unless there's some deforestation going on to erase it. And things will be especially bad if the implementation does not use something like tail recursion modulo cons—a naive implementation will essentially reverse the first list twice, which is not so nice.